# How to create an advenced setup like those of MSOffice,Nero,Adobe etc

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-project

I've completed my windows project in C# and I want to build a nice setup which has the following features:

1.Shows the popular I agree/disagree page.

2.Shows which files are being copied/updated.

3.any other custom activity I want to add.

I've built 2-3 basic setups in VS2008(setup wizard) but I don't know if it is possible to achieve the above requirements in visual studio's setup wizard?

Any other third party software to build nice windows setups are also welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should really start asking for money for giving this answer :P  The [WiX Toolkit](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is just what you are looking for.  Everything is done through XML formatted files and then compiled into MSI's (or other formats) from there.  You can design your own dialogs, add progress messages/bars, Custom Actions galour, and so much more for the low low price of...nothing.  It is completely free.  Their is a little bit to learn, but the main page has a link to an amazing tutorial that will get you going in no time.